# Variable not loaded before the file is loaded in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny App where the user loads the data at the time of execution. When I run my Shiny App, below is the screen that opens. On the right I want it to display nothing before we load the data but as you see a warning is displayed at the end.

I have tried putting inherit.aes = False since ggplot is using the execution_date column from the data but this still doesn't work.

[image: Initial warning]

Below is my code:

```
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

#install.packages("shinyWidgets")
library(shinyWidgets)
df <- read_xlsx("Results.xlsx", sheet =  1)
lst.measures <- as.list(unique(df$DQ_Check))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data Quality Result Monitoring Dashboard"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                accept = c(".xlsx")
      ),


    radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                 choices = c(Head = "head",
                             All = "all"),
                 selected = "head"),

  pickerInput(
    inputId = "myPicker", 
    label = "Which DQ Checks would you like to see in more detail?", 
    choices = lst.measures, 
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = pickerOptions(
      actionsBox = TRUE, 
      size = 10,
      selectedTextFormat = 'count > 3'
    )
  )  
  ),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    h4("Chart"),
    plotOutput("linechart"),

    h4("Observations"),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
)    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram'
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read_xlsx(inFile$datapath, sheet =  1)

    df

  })

  output$linechart <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(df(),aes(x= Execution_Date,y=Fail_Count, group(Execution_Date)),inherit.aes = FALSE)+geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    dataset <- df()
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(dataset))
    }
    else {
      return(dataset)
    }

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `req()` command: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

Comment: Also I think you meant `group=Execution_Date' rather than `group(Execution_Date)` but i'm not sure why you have that at all when that's also your `x` value. Have you successfully made the plot you want outside of shiny before? Are you sure that's the syntax you want?